# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I upgraded Spring boot version 3.0.2 and i try graalvm nativeCompile that is error happened.

I run this application normal way it is OK but i try executable file show this error.

```
 Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector': Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector': Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
```

i try use this annotation register bean , unfortunately repeat again error

```
@RegisterReflectionForBinding
```

that is my security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

       @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .headers()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(getAuthContext(),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthContextFilter1 getAuthContext() {
        return new AuthContextFilter1();
    }

}


that is my authContextFilter class


@Slf4j
public class AuthContextFilter1 extends GenericFilterBean {

    private static final String X_CLIENT_ID = "ID";
    private static final String X_CLIENT_ROLES = "ROLE";
    private static final String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String clientId = httpServletRequest.getHeader(X_CLIENT_ID);
        String roles = httpServletRequest.getHeader(X_CLIENT_ROLES);

        if (Objects.nonNull(clientId)) {
            try {
                if ((!StringUtils.isEmpty(roles))) {
                    authorities = Arrays.stream(roles.split(","))
                            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_PREFIX + role))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                }

                Authentication auth = new CustomAuthentication(clientId, authorities);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Auth context initialization failed for clientId: {}, message: {}",
                        clientId, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same problem, and the cause was the dependency "springdoc-openapi-ui".

```
// implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.14")
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2")
```